# Date formating not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have been working with PHP for several months and just started teaching myself ajax. My first project is to send variables from a PHP form via jQuery to another PHP which serves as the action. I want to find the difference between two dates&times and return an echo response of numerous calculations back to the PHP form page. The good news is that ajax works as expected and displays the calculations on the form page, but only if I use a hardcode date-time ($start) to begin the calculations. If I try to format a date ($start) with the variables from the form page, ajax returns nothing. If this question has been answered, please direct me to that location.

```
$TravelYear  = $_POST['TravelYear'];  
$TravelMonth = $_POST['TravelMonth'];  
$TravelDate  = $_POST['TravelDate'];  
$TravelHour  = $_POST['TravelHour'];  
$TimeZone   = $_POST['TimeZone'];  
date_default_timezone_set($TimeZone);  

// this does not work  
$start = date('Y-m-d G:i:s',strtotime($TravelYear.'-'.$TravelMonth.'-'.$TravelDate.' '.$TravelHour.":00:00")); 

// this works  
$start = date_create('2015-07-10 14:30:00');

$end = date_create(); // Current time and date  
$diff = date_diff( $start, $end ); // Find the difference

// lots of calculations
```

Comment: I think the $start that doesn't work is a string and the $start that does work is a DateTime object.  I think date_diff() only works with DateTime objects.  Try using date_create() in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `date_diff` expects a datetime object not a date string.

According to the documentation, date_diff is an alias for `DateTime::diff()`

Use:

```
$start = date_create($TravelYear.'-'.$TravelMonth.'-'.$TravelDate.' '.$TravelHour.':00:00');
```

Comment: Thanks, Rich. Your format works. I had actually tried date_create but it failed for perhaps some other reason, which led me down the wrong road.